# cannot boot ubuntu 12.04 after dual-boot installation on hp xw8200

Tags: dual-boot

I have a 160GB drive and a 2TB drive (both internal) on a HP xw8200
I have windows xp on the 160 GB drive. 
partitioned a /boot 1GB, 10GB swap, 100GB /, and a 400GB /home on the 2TB drive.
Chose to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside XP, but just before the installation was complete, error about grub not being able to install.

Tried boot-repair, but still cannot boot into Ubuntu.
Pls. find details at http://paste.ubuntu.com/998508/

Your help would be greatly appreciated,
Balu

Comment: can you tell us the device you are trying to install grub into is `dynamic` or `basic`? You can get this info by running`diskmgmt.msc` in windows. Or you can post a screenshot of disk management window. (the window opened by above command)

Comment: Why not try installing grub once again from live?

Comment: Web-E: All my partitions are basic. Apparently I cannot post images since I'm a new user. But pls. find the image at 
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Grk.png


harisibrahimkv: I've installed and reinstalled GRUB many times (trying on different partitions), but to no avail.

Thanks,
Balu

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 along side Windows 7 on a 2TB internal. I installed Windows 7, left 1TB for Ubuntu during the Windows 7 installation, but when I boot from the Ubuntu 12.04 CD there's no "install along side Windows 7" option, only "use entire disk" and "something else".

According to the disk manager in Windows 7, the layout of my Windows 7 partition is "simple", and the type is "basic".

Have noticed a number of posts from people experiencing the same problem, have yet to find any answers.

Comment: Scott: Do you know if this is not the case with Ubuntu 11.10? Pls. let me know so that I may try to put 11.10

Thanks,
Balu

Comment: The problem was due to the 2TB drive. Booting from the Ubuntu 12.04 CD into Ubuntu (instead of the installer) and then installing and running "FixParts" solved the problem: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/files/gptfdisk/0.8.4/fixparts-binaries/

Answer (score 0):

Your Ubuntu partition ends far from the start of the disk.
Try this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1998257